# Generate a random number from a lognormal distribution in C++

Tags: c++11

I am using g++ with gcc version 4.6.3. I want to generate random numbers from a lognormal distribution. Obviously I can't use the new functions in C++11 for generating random numbers. What is the easiest way to do that in C++0x?

Comment: If it's not included with the compiler, consider [Boost Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Random has random numbers generator and log-normal distribution.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions

It works with older C++ standard.

Comment: Thank you, I used Boost.Random and it worked for me.